# AppMap recorder fails to start with unknown API Endpoint error

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, recording

I'm running a SpringBoot 2.7.12 reactive stack application on my Macbook Pro. Using IntelliJ Ultimate with Java 17, MariaDB, R2DBC and some AWS service integrations.
Installed the IntelliJ plugin for AppMap.
Running IntegrationTest works fine - impressive.

However, trying to start a recording fails due to the endpoint not existing in the application.
Following is a log snipped:

```
2023-06-10 10:22:12.845 DEBUG [CUSTOMER-SERVICE,e9a3b813acbf717e,e9a3b813acbf717e] 23817 --- [               parallel-9] z.c.m.customer.filter.RequestWebFilter   : Received api endpoint hit : [path : /_appmap/record]
2023-06-10 10:22:12.848 ERROR [CUSTOMER-SERVICE,e9a3b813acbf717e,e9a3b813acbf717e] 23817 --- [               parallel-9] z.c.m.c.e.e.CustomAttributes             : Exception happened => message: 404 NOT_FOUND "No matching handler" stacktrace: [org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$createNotFoundError$3(DispatcherHandler.java:159)]
```

I have not added the Maven build configuration to the pom.xml file. From what I can see from the documentation it is not required.

Any pointers to get this going?
Really looks like a super cool utility.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was addressed in the AppMap Java agent v.1.20.0.